# How to find different versions of a same parent in a complex maven dependency tree?

Tags: maven, dependencies, parent-pom

I have a maven module with many dependencies. Some dependencies are managed by my team, some others are managed by my company and others are open source.

When I build this module, I can see that many versions of the same parent pom are downloaded into my local repository:

```
com\my_company\parent\18\parent-18.pom
com\my_company\parent\22\parent-22.pom
com\my_company\parent\25\parent-25.pom
```

My goal is to try to understand which dependencies are referencing these parents versions.
That way I can update or ask people to update their modules to use the latest parent.

I would like output somehow like the one from **mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose** but with parents.

I tried to find a solution in maven dependency plugin. I found **mvn dependency:list -DincludeParents** which displays parents. But it does not indicate the reason why they are in the list.

I found also **mvn dependency:resolve -D includeParents** which seems exactly the same as dependency:list...

I found this interesting plugin:
https://github.com/ExampleDriven/hierarchy-maven-plugin
but it does not display all the parents. It only displays parents that are defining used dependencies versions.

I found this one too:
https://github.com/umut/parent-checker
but I cannot ask all teams to use this plugin.

Comment: We check parent POM versions on the build server right before the build. Would this be an alternative for you?

Comment: There are too many dependencies (and transitive dependencies) built on many servers. It would take a lot of time to find the appropriate build jobs and inspect the poms.

Comment: Why are interested in the parent POMs of your dependencies? Is there a special aspect that you want to check?

Comment: First reason: When we deliver a product, we must also deliver the source code and the way to build it. So we are delivering a local maven repository with all needed dependencies. And we found out that there are many versions of parents in this repository. That is not clean.
Second reason, there are just so many things defined in our parents like plugins versions and configurations, variables that will be used in the children and so on. As a result I would prefer to see all modules with the same and up to date parents.

Comment: Couldn't you just run an `update-parent` on _all_ projects every few months?

Comment: For sure that would solve my issue but I don't have the right to do that. I am responsible for only few modules. So I would like to only detect which modules have old parent versions and then I will try to find corresponding teams to ask them politely to update them.

Comment: I see. But wouldn't it be a good question for the team that manages the builds?

Comment: The team that manages the builds? Do you mean the guys that enforce standardization and quality of building processes across the company? Those who manage and maintain shared tools like Jenkins and artifact repositories? The experts that can help us and provide advices related to continuous integration and delivery? Such a thing existed few years ago, but it is now gone. I don’t know if the company wanted to “cut the costs” or if it some kind of new “DevOps” autonomy policy.

Comment: I am sorry for your loss.